# PHP File renaming gone wrong

Tags: php

I have 12 css files in my system, and I rename them whenever users want to change style. I store current style in the database, and rename style.css to style`$Color`.css, renaming Style`$Requestedcolor`.css to style.css right after that. Here's the code:

```
if ($_POST['blue'] == "Blue")
{
    if(file_exists('./css/styleblue.css'))
    {
    $old = './css/style.css';
    $new = './css/style'.$Color.'.css';
    $old1 = './css/styleblue.css';
    $new1 = './css/style.css';
    rename($old, $new);
    rename($old1, $new1);
    $newcolor = "blue";
    $idnum = "1";
    mysql_query("UPDATE company SET Color = '$newcolor' WHERE ID = '$idnum'");
    }
}
```

Problem is, I sometimes (not always, finding it very hard to diagnose when and why) end up loosing a file, while system grabs a completely random .css file, renames it to style.css and writes the correct $newcolor to the database. Maybe the renaming goes too fast? Or should I grab for each of these ifs (there's 12) info for `$Color` value?

Comment: The code is open to SQL injections. Imagine `$idnum` being `' OR 1 = 1 --`. That'd change all the colors! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ..as the query would then be `UPDATE company SET Color = 'FF0000' WHERE ID = '' OR 1 = 1 -- '` which would set `Color` to `FF0000` on the rows where `1` is equal to `1` (every single row, as 1 is always the same as 1).

Comment: have you try using the user_id as part of the file rename

Comment: Thanks for that, I do plan a complete revamp of the code, however, I don't see how someone would mess up with this, as both variables are static, non-dependent on user input. I am looking into PDO, and I will update everything, however, I would like to have 100% operational system before I do that =)

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza my question might be missing info. Table "company" has only 1 row, I use it to store info relevant to the site itself (name, text displayed on the home page, contact E-mail, color theme in use etc) so the query is fine. My renames are the one that tend to mess up

Answer (score 0):

I have a sneaking suspicion that `$Color` occasionally doesn't get set before you start renaming files, are you verifying that your query completes and returns a result before running the block of code you've posted?

A better idea would be instead of constantly renaming the files you just change the filename in the `<link>` tag that you output on the page? That way you don't have to worry about the renaming process going sideways, or the new style.css not overwriting the old style.css in the client's cache.

I have a second sneaking suspicion that you're not making full use of CSS inheritance either, given that you're using a generic filename of 'style.css'. A somewhat better approach would be:

#### PHP/HTML

```
<? $color = 'blue'; ?>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.<?= $color ?>.css">
</head>
```

#### style.css

Contains layout-related directives and default colors, eg:

```
body {
  font-family: Sans;
  background-color: grey;
}

#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

#### theme.blue.css

Contains just color-related directives to override those previously defined, eg:

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

#container {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: I see your point, however, this is built already with 50+ pages. I understand css inheritance, it's not done proper at the moment, but it kinda works. I do fetch the `$Color` value upon opening that page, however, I have just updated it so that it fetches it again once the button is clicked, and it works =) I plan on updating this so that all those `<link rel..>` are in a file called style.php for instance, so I can `include "style.php";` everywhere and simply have that file pull information from the database. At the moment, this is  a hard upgrade so I'm just looking to patch it =)